# field doesn't have a default value in yii

Tags: sql, yii

[SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'project_budget' doesn't have a default value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w2Rv6.png)

Field 'project_budget' doesn't have a default value

Comment: [0] => HY000
    [1] => 1364
    [2] => Field 'project_budget' doesn't have a default value

Comment: You should post here what have you tried? take the pain of writing here.

Comment: jack jay . all code is working in other server . but it is not running innew server . This is caused by the STRICT_TRANS_TABLES SQL mode defined in the. i want to remove this mode . but don tknow how to remove this

Answer (score 0):

It says that Looged_out column does not have default value, it is not null and you did not pass any value to it

Comment: but this can save as null

Answer (score 0):

> First try to post whatever code or query along with your question. [no
>   imgur.com for codes].

The error says that `Logged_out` column doesnt not have default value. This error is possibly rise because you may be defined `Logged_out` as `NOT NULL` without specifying explicitly its default value using `DEFAULT`. Now you also don't provide `Logged_out` value in your `insert` query. hence the error is thrown.

**Solution:**  Either set a Default value for `Logged_out` column as,

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_session_detalis ALTER COLUMN logged_out SET DEFAULT 'someValue';
```

Or provide value of `logged_out` in your insert query.

> How can sql save `null` when you have `NOT NULL`?

Comment: it is working on  another domain . but on new domain it giving errors like i posted

Comment: domain i didn't get it.